# Mapeando um array com possíveis subarrays como elementos

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando criar uma função que mapeie um array para outro newArray. Se um dos elementos do array for um `array`, quero mapear todos os seus subElementos para o newArray.

Portanto:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1]]
```

Deveria retornar

> [1,2,3,4,5,1,3,2,4,1]

Meu código está assim:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1]]

var newArray = array.map(function(element){

    if (typeof(element) === "object"){
        element.forEach(function(subElement){
            return(subElement);
        })
    } else {
        return(element);
    }

})

newArray;
```

Mas newArray retorna:

> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transforme o array multidimensional em string, depois transforme em array:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1]];
console.log(array.join().split(",")); // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "3", "2", "4", "1"]
```

**Caso seja necessário apenas números:**

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1]];
var novoArray = array.join().split(",").map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item);
});
console.log(novoArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Essa abordagem não funciona se os elementos contém strings com vírgulas: `flatten("a,b") --> ["a", "b"]`

Comment: Solução simples para o problema à mão.

Answer (score 10):

No teu código estás a usar o [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), mas esse método retorna um array com o mesmo numero de elementos, por isso não vai funcionar pois o array final que queres terá mais elementos que o primeiro.

Podes usar o "novo" [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para fazer isso.

Seria assim:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 3, 2, 4, 1]];
var novoArray = array.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}, []);
console.log(novoArray); // dá [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zacjndf/

Outra maneira mais "gambiarra" podia ser assim:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 3, 2, 4, 1]];
var novoArray = [].concat.apply([], array)
console.log(novoArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zacjndf/1/

## Recursivamente:

Se precisares de usar arrays com *N* niveis de profundidade precisas de uma função recursiva. Aqui fica uma sugestão que [aparenta ser a mais rápida](http://jsperf.com/flatten-de-array-em-javascript/3):

```
function alisar(arr) {
    var novo = [];
    function redutor(arr, el) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
            while ((el = arr.pop()) || arr.length) redutor(el);
        } else {
            novo.push(arr);
        }
    }
    redutor(arr);
    return novo.reverse();
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmou4yvz/1

Answer (score 6):

O nome mais comum para essa função que você quer é "flatten". Pra mim, a maneira mais fácil de implementar essa função é com recursão.

```
function flatten(inputArray){
    var out = [];
    function go(x){
       if(Array.isArray(x)){
           for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
               go(x[i]);
           }
       }else{
           out.push(x);
       }
    }
    go(inputArray);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Hugo, você consegue me dizer o que está errado com o meu algoritmo?

Comment: Quando `typeof(element) === "object"` a callback do `map` retorna `undefined` porque não tem `return`. O return dentro do forEach não conta - ele faz a callback do foreach retornar, não a callback do map.  Resumindo: não dá pra resolver esse problema com mágica, tem que fazer a recursão mesmo.

Comment: Sua resposta tem a melhor performance entre as recursivas: http://jsperf.com/flatten-de-array-em-javascript

Comment: @bfavaretto juntei também uma função recursiva: http://jsperf.com/flatten-de-array-em-javascript/2 Hugo: `+1` por me teres feito perder tempo a melhorar a minha resposta :)

Answer (score 6):

Você já tem várias soluções nas outras respostas, então vou apenas explicar o problema do seu código. O problema está neste trecho:

```
element.forEach(function(subElement){
    return(subElement);
})
```

Você tem um retorno dentro do callback do `forEach`, mas esse retorno não se aplica ao callback do `map` como você parece esperar. Dessa maneira, quando o seu código segue o caminho do `typeof(element) === "object"`, o callback do `map` não tem nenhum retorno definido. E em JS funções sem `return` retornam implicitamente `undefined`, que é o que está indo parar no seu resultado.

Como não tenho uma solução a acrescentar, aproveito o espaço para dizer que entre as respostas com recursão apresentadas até agora, [a do @hugomg é a que tem melhor performance](http://jsperf.com/flatten-de-array-em-javascript).

Comment: Eu só adicionaria que o forEach vai retornar um `Array` da mesma forma, o que não dá o efeito que ele deseja...

Comment: Como assim? O `forEach` retorna `undefined` (se o código fosse `return element.forEach...`).

Comment: você está certo, me confundi porque eu dei o `return` no element... :/

Answer (score 4):

O que você quer fazer parece ser um `flat`. Para isso basta fazer o seguinte:

```
function flat(arr){
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] instanceof Array){
            ret = ret.concat(flat(arr[i]));
        }else{
            ret.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Isso deve resolver isso seu problema.

Comment: Felipe, você sabe me dizer o que há de errado com o meu algoritmo?

Comment: o @bfavaretto já respondeu [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69987/1333)

Answer (score 4):

já tem algumas respostas aqui, mas eu acho que tem uma forma mais "limpa":

```
function flatten (elemento){
  if(Array.isArray(elemento))
    return elemento.reduce(function(anterior,atual){
            return anterior.concat(flatten(atual))
          },[]);
  else return [elemento];
}
```

Comment: Essa função tem complexidade quadrática no pior caso, quando a entrada tem "profundidade" N: Algo como `[1,[2,[3,[4,[5]]]]]`

Answer (score 4):

Podes criar o teu próprio mapeamento:

```js
Array.prototype.hasObject = function(){
    for (i in this)
        if(typeof this[i] == "object")
            return true;

    return false;
}

Array.prototype.flatten  = function(){
    if (typeof condition == 'undefined') 
        condition = function(){return true;};

    narray = [];

    this.forEach(function(element){
        if (typeof element == 'object'){
            for(i in element){
                if (!element.hasOwnProperty(i))
                    continue;
                narray.push(element[i]);
            }
        } else 
            narray.push(element);
    });
    
    if (narray.hasObject())
        return narray.flatten();
    else return narray;
}
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1, [555,555,654, ['eu to malucooooo!']]]];
var newArray = array.flatten();

console.log(newArray)
```

Uso:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1, [555,555,654, ['eu to malucooooo!']]]];
var newArray = array.flatten();
```

Saída:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 555, 555, 654, "eu to malucooooo!"]

#### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83cz4x9f/)

Answer (score 2):

**Atualização 2021**
Você pode utilizar o método `flat` do `array`:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,3,2,4,1]];
console.log(array.flat());
```

---

> [**`flat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
>
> O método `flat()` cria um novo array com todos elementos sub-arrays concatenados nele de forma recursiva até a profundidade especificada.