# Há alguma alternativa no JavaScript semelhante ao "flatMap" do Java 8?

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando fazer um mapeamento de elementos que me retorna um vetor. Porém, eu já estou fazendo um trabalho em cima de um `array`, então o simples `map` vai me retornar um vetor contendo vetores.

No caso, eu tenho um vetor de objetos não homogêneos, variando nomes dos campos e quantidade; por exemplo:

```
[
    {
        "cod": "1",
        "ds": "marmota 1"
    },
    {
        "cod_2": "1",
        "ds": "marmota 2"
    },
    {
        "cod": "2",
        "descricao": "descritiva"
    },
    {
        "cod": "3",
        "descricao": "descritivamente",
        "payload": "baleia"
    }
]
```

Eu gostaria que me fosse retornado algo assim:

```
[ "cod", "ds", "cod_2", "ds", "cod", "descricao", "cod", "descricao", "payload" ]
```

Ou assim (com eliminação de duplicatas):

```
[ "cod", "ds", "cod_2", "descricao", "payload" ]
```

> Esse segundo caso não me é extremamente importante, pois [posso utilizar o `Set`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313890/64969) para tal fim

Ao tentar fazer o mapeamento usado `Object.keys()`, não obtenho o resultado desejado:

```js
let dados = [ { "cod": "1", "ds": "marmota 1" }, { "cod_2": "1", "ds": "marmota 2" }, { "cod": "2", "descricao": "descritiva" }, { "cod": "3", "descricao": "descritivamente", "payload": "baleia" } ];

console.log(dados.map(l => Object.keys(l)));
```

porém o resultado é um vetor com vetores dentro:

```
[ 
  ["cod","ds"] , 
  ["cod_2","ds"] , 
  ["cod","descricao"] , 
  ["cod","descricao","payload"] 
]
```

Se eu estivesse usando Java 8, seria algo como a operação de `flatMap` das `streams`. O equivalente do meu resultado desejado seria algo assim:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> dados = ...; // fica povoado como os dados adequados
Set<String> resultado = dados.stream().flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

O ideal, para mim, no JavaScript seria algo que eu pudesse continuar trabalhando como uma `stream` do Java 8. Na verdade, ainda tem algumas operações de `filter` que eu gostaria de fazer antes de coletar os dados finais.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na [resposta do hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69980/132) ou na [resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69981/132) ou na do [KaduAmaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70003/132) nessa pergunta que marquei como duplicata.

Comment: @VictorStafusa , parece que minha questão é apenas um caso especial dessa que você indicou. Eu estava procurando por algo como a do Sergio (primeiro excerto, principalmente). Quando abrir o computador eu marco como duplicata exata

Comment: Aproveito para dizer que o [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) está também a ser incorporado em `Array` e que fará isso direto numa função. Infelizmente o suporte neste momento é muito escasso, mas até tem um *polyfill*.

Comment: @Isac também tem o `flatMap` que está a caminho de ser tornado oficial. Foi lá na verdade que achei a solução semelhante à do Sergio, com `reduce`

Comment: @Isac, a referência do [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) e de onde eu peguei o [como fazer via `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternativa)

Comment: Sim, eu suspeito que quem criou um criou o outro também, dada a semelhança e suporte igual. Até o reduce sugerido de alternativa é igual.

Comment: Sei que a pergunta tem um tempinho mas as vezes isso pode te interessar  **flatMap - Functional JavaScript - Supercharged:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgrila9cbzg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usando `.reduce()` com `.forEach()` irá adicionar os nomes das chaves dos objetos na array `res[]`:

```js
let dados = [ {"cod": "1", "ds": "marmota 1"}, {"cod_2": "1", "ds": "marmota 2" }, {"cod": "3", "descricao": "descritivamente" , "payload": "baleia"}];

const res = dados.reduce((i, e)=>{
   Object.keys(e).forEach(e=>{
      i.push(e);
   });
   return i;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Chegou perto. Só que podem ser múltiplas chaves, não apenas só 2 por objeto. Vou editar para deixar mais clara a pergunta

Comment: Alterei o código. []s